# Performing histogram streching using gdal_translate?

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I have some rasters I want to perform histogram stretching on, and I want to use only open source tools, preferably using shell/bash command line.

I was thinking of using gdal_translate with setting -scale for minimum and maximum, but maybe there is something else that can automatically set min and max, do you know about something like that, please?

Is there in gdal_translate possibility to scale with bigger color depth than 2^8?

Comment: I was going to suggest [gdal_contrast_stretch](https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts/wiki/Gdal-contrast-stretch) but I see from your recent edit that you want >8 bit output (plus that requires compilation).

Comment: -scale is not limited to 8-bit. Define a higher bit depth output format and you can use any values within the valid range.

Comment: You can use gdal_translate or use VRT with look up tables for advanced stretching (LUT)